# My script doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to change the required message for the elements but I don't know why my script doesn't work! Are the src's correct?!

```
<head>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#form1 input[type=text]').on('change invalid', function () {
        var textfield = $(this).get(0);

        // 'setCustomValidity not only sets the message, but also marks
        // the field as invalid. In order to see whether the field really is
        // invalid, we have to remove the message first
        textfield.setCustomValidity('');

        if (!textfield.validity.valid) {
            textfield.setCustomValidity('Some message... ');
        }
    });
</script>
```

And here is the body.

```
    <form id="form1" class="form-basic" action="~/MortgageAndRent/InsertMortgageAndRent/" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="@Model.UserId" />

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>Province</span>
                <input type="text" name="AddressViewModel.Province" value="@Model.AddressViewModel.Province" required />
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">
            <label>
                <span>City</span>
                <input type="text" name="AddressViewModel.City" value="@Model.AddressViewModel.City" required />
            </label>
        </div>
```

.
.
.

Comment: You have to learn how to debug your code first. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code

Comment: Your `#form2 input[type=text]` element doesn't exist when you're running your code setting up the event handler. See the linked question's answers. (You'll also need an element with `id="form2"` around the input, or to change the selector.)

Answer (score -2):

This `$('#form2 input[type=text]').on('change invalid', function () { var textfield = $(this).get(0);});` you had forgotten }; but in your html you are not declaring the id of form2 so i think this `$('input[type=text]').on('change invalid', function () { var textfield = $(this).get(0);});`

Comment: You also forgot to close `)` at the end :)

Comment: Yeah just saw that thanks for saying it, writing code on phone isnt great :)

Comment: @NotanNimda. Thank you very much for your reply. In this link  http://jsfiddle.net/zpkKv/2/  } and ) is at the end.

Comment: What src is needed to run the script??

Comment: You need jquery but if i were you i would remove the ~ in the src

Comment: @notanNimda I did. But didn't work! :(